# Why are exported row names always off by 1 in R?

Tags: r

In R, when exporting CSVs why are column names always off by 1?

```
x=matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2)
rownames(x) <- c("row1", "row2")
colnames(x) <- c("col1", "col2")

>x
          col1 col2
    row1    1    3
    row2    2    4

write.table(x,"/Users/username/Desktop/x.csv", sep=",")
```

The column names are always shifted one column to the left:

```
*The resulting CSV looks like this when opened in Excel:*
 col1   col2    
 row1   1      3
 row2   2      4

*The resulting CSV looks like this when opened in TextEdit:*
 "col1","col2"
 "row1",1,3
 "row2",2,4
```

I've always had a problem with this, but now that my code is being used for professional purposes rather than for just playing around with data, I need to figure out how to avoid this. I have a feeling it's a fairly easy fix.

Comment: Presumably there actually are commas in the output? Otherwise there's something else you're not telling us...

Comment: I'm opening the output in Excel (which is the default program on my computer for opening CSVs), so there are no commas (but I suppose that the commas are what tells Excel where to make a new cell).

Comment: try opening it in a plain text editor

Comment: @SebastianRaschka see my edit above. Even so, there is still an off-by-one error for the column names.

Comment: There is no problem. That is what is supposed to happen. What value do you expect to be in that place?

Comment: I suppose I just expect a blank in that space.  I am using the R code to power data that is being displayed on a website, and the lack of an initial space is causing off-by-one column name errors on the website, as well.

Comment: From `?write.table`: "By default there is no column name for a column of row names. If col.names = NA and row.names = TRUE a blank column name is added, which is the convention used for CSV files to be read by spreadsheets."

Answer (score 7):

The documentation has the answer for you:

> By default there is no column name for a column of row names. If
>   col.names = NA and row.names = TRUE a blank column name is added,
>   which is the convention used for CSV files to be read by spreadsheets.
>   Note that such CSV files can be read in R by    read.csv(file =
>   "", row.names = 1)

So, either use `write.csv` or add `col.names = NA` to `write.table`.